# how can i solve this issue? I'm trying to call the currency_mapping in the KV file but it's not working

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

```
MDIconButton:
            id: currency_button_1
            icon: root.currency_mapping[root.ids.currency_button_1.currency]
            on_release: app.change_currency(root.ids.currency_button_1.currency)

        MDIconButton:
            id: currency_button_2
            icon: root.currency_mapping[root.ids.currency_button_2.currency]
            on_release: app.change_currency(root.ids.currency_button_2.currency)


class Currency_ConverterApp(MDApp):
    currency_mapping = {
        'USD': 'us.png',
        'EUR': '27018.png',
    }


def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def change_currency(self, currency):
        screen = self.root.get_screen('converter_calculator')
        screen.ids.input_field.text = ''
        screen.ids.result_label.text = ''
        screen.ids.currency_button_1.icon = self.currency_mapping[currency]  # Update button 1
        screen.ids.currency_button_2.icon = self.currency_mapping[currency]  # Update button 2
        screen.ids.currency_button_1.currency = currency  # Set currency attribute for button 1
        screen.ids.currency_button_2.currency = currency  # Set currency attribute for button 2
        screen.current_currency = currencyy
```

I tried calling the `currency_mapping` in the `kv` file but I receive an error `msg` (object has no attribute `currency_mapping`.

I'm trying to create a currency converter app in `kivymd`

Answer (score 1):

Your `kv` code:

```
icon: root.currency_mapping[root.ids.currency_button_1.currency]
```

is trying to access `currency_mapping` of `root`. But in `kv` the `root` is the root object of the current rule, which in your case is the `MDIconButton`. The problem is that the `MDIconButton` has no attribute `currency_mapping` (as the error explains). The fix is to change `root` to `app` in the above line, since `currency_mapping` is an attribute of the `app`.

You will likely have similar problems with the rest of that line, but you have not posted enough code to determine that.

Comment: thanks for the help but the error has change to ('MDIconButton' object has no attribute 'currency')